# Pandas Groupby barplot for a logical matrix

Tags: python, pandas, plot, group-by

```
a 0 0 0 0 1  
a 0 0 0 1 1  
a 1 0 0 1 1  
b 1 0 0 1 1  
c 0 0 1 1 1  
c 1 0 0 0 0   
c 0 1 0 0 0
```

If I have a Pandas dataframe like the one above, how could I go about grouping the data by a, b and c and then plotting the sum/count of each column?

Ideally, I'd have 3 groups in my barchart, each with 5 bars representing the sum/count for that column in that group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `groupby` method on a dataframe to create a dataframe groupby object.  Calling `sum` on the groupby object creates a new dataframe that is a pivot of the original dataframe.  From there you can call `plot` to make the bar chart.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'type': ['a','a','a','b','c','c','c'],
     'v1': [0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
     'v2': [0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
     'v3': [0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
     'v4': [0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
     'v5': [1,1,1,1,1,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
gb_sum = df.groupby('type').sum()
gb_sum.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]